# Bringing back fields by internal name in SharePoint REST

Tags: 2013, web-services, rest

Let's say I have the query:

```
http://thisbox/_api/lists/getbytitle('ThisList')/items?$select=*
```

But instead of "*" for selecting fields, I have a list of Field Internal Names and/or GUID's. I'd like to use to select from (I can retrieve either from elsewhere in my code).  However the SELECT option seems to want to get only external (Visible) field names.  Thoughts?

Comment: what happend when you provide the internal name in you query? seems to be working for me. what type of fields you trying to access it?

Comment: For example on a "Modified by" field which has a typical internal name of "Editor" in an internal list: /items?$select=Editor returns "The query to field 'Editor' is not valid. The $select query string must specify the target fields and the $expand query string must contains Editor

Comment: @tekiegreg, see my answer (section: About deferred fields)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your first REST query should work as long as internal name of the position column is same. You can check  by running below query which will display the metadata for columns along with their columns.

```
http://thisbox/_api/lists/getbytitle('ThisList')/items
```

you will see something like this:

```
<d:User_x0020_ModifiedId m:type="Edm.Int32">12</d:User_x0020_ModifiedId>
```

Now you run the query like this.

```
http://thisbox/_api/lists/getbytitle('ThisList')/items?$select=User_x0020_ModifiedId
```

Answer (score 7):

The query `/_api/lists/getbytitle('<list title>')/items?$select=*` returns list items for *visible fields* only ([SP.Field.hidden property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245336.aspx) is set to `false`).

To be more precise the expression `$select=*` returns:

- `visible` fields values (query that returns visible field names: `/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('<list title>')/fields?$select=InternalName&$filter=Hidden eq false`)
- `FileSystemObjectType` hidden field value
- *not all* visible field values are returned, for example *ItemChildCount* is not available:

**How to return an additional fields**

In order to return *an additional fields*, the field name(s) have to be specified explicitly using `$select` query option. For example, to return hidden system field `FileRef` you could utilize the following query:

```
/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('<list title>')/items?$select=FileRef
```

or

```
/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('<list title>')/items?$select=FileRef,*
```

> While the first query will return only a single `FileRef` field value, the
>   latter query will return list field values plus `FileRef` field value.

**About deferred fields**

For some field types such as [SP.FieldUser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246199.aspx) or [SP.FieldLookup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff408733(v=office.14).aspx) `$select` expressions returns only the identifier (ID) of the list item that this  field is referring to. For example, the query: `/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('<list title>')/items` for `Editor` field returns only user id (`EditorId`)
For that case  `$expand` query option comes to the rescue that is intended for retrieving *projected* fields, for example the query:

```
/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('<list title>')/items?$select=Editor/Title,Editor/Id&$expand=Editor
```

returns `Title` and `Id` properties of `Editor` field

Answer (score 2):

Not a direct way. Select only responds to the name/GUID. You would have to do an additional pull to

`http://thisbox/_api/lists/getbytitle('ThisList')/Fields`

in order to return the list of names, internal names and GUIDs and cross-reference accordingly.